# SignalR does not work in a VsCode extension

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, signalr

I'm following the official docs to add signalR to my VsCode extension.
My dependencies in the `package.json` are:

```
    "dependencies": {
        "@microsoft/signalr": "^6.0.8",
        "@taqueria/protocol": "^0.12.0",
        "cli-table3": "^0.6.2",
        "comment-json": "^4.1.1",
        "node-fetch": "^3.2.10",
        "promise-memoize": "^1.2.1",
        "rambda": "^7.0.1",
        "rxjs": "^7.5.6",
        "semver": "^7.3.7"
    }
```

But I get this error: `requireFunc is not a function`.

The offending code is:

```
        if (Platform.isNode && typeof require !== "undefined") {
            // In order to ignore the dynamic require in webpack builds we need to do this magic
            // @ts-ignore: TS doesn't know about these names
            const requireFunc = typeof __webpack_require__ === "function" ? __non_webpack_require__ : require;
            webSocketModule = requireFunc("ws");
            eventSourceModule = requireFunc("eventsource");
        }
```

in `node_modules/@microsoft/signalr/src/HttpConnection.ts`

While debugging, it seems that all three variables `__non_webpack_require__`, `__non_webpack_require__`, and `require` are not defined.